# Create mediawiki template with html inside

Tags: mediawiki

MediaWiki creates `<pre>` tags after parse {{Template}} with html code.
How to prevent this tags?

Example template:

```
<span style="color:#FF0000">{{{1}}}</span>
```

In wiki html page looks like:

```
<pre>
    <span style="color:#FF0000">Some Text</span>
</pre>
```

In basic templates like: 
    My name is {{{1}}}
no problem with `<pre>` tags.

PS `<pre>` tag creates unwanted borders around elements in MediaWiki.

Comment: No it does not. It only creates them if you indent some markup (either in the template or outside at the inclusion) with one (or more) spaces.

Comment: Thanks. That's resolve problem.

Comment: @Sonique then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bergi's solution: avoid to indent some markup (either in the template or outside at the inclusion) with one (or more) spaces.